# Overriding fetch() method in backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to override the default fetch() method in a Backbone model, thus calling it only when needed.

Something like this:

```
Account.Check = Backbone.Model.extend({
    model : Account.Item,

    url : Settings.Url.checkAccount,

    fetch : function(options) {         
                if (someCondition()) {
                    // do some stuff
            } else {
               super.fetch(options);
                }
    }
});
```

My question is how to provide the same behaviour as the default fetch() method in the *// do some other stuff* part?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should do it...

```
fetch : function(options) {         
           if (someCondition()) {
              // do some stuff
           } else {
              this.constructor.__super__.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
              // Or (less flexible)
              Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);    
           }
         }
```